# Цепочка выбора с telegram_bot_calendar python

Tags: python, telegram

Хэло!

Есть цепочка выборов "выбор1" >> "выбор2" >> "дейт пикер"

"выбор1" и "выбор2" работают через callback_data. Спокойно пробрасываю нужные мне параметры. Тут проблемы нет

Следующим этапом идет "дейт пикер", подключенный из либы telegram_bot_calendar. На сколько я понял из документации и исследования исходников либы, прокинуть мою callback_data через этот календарь невозможно... (если не форкать) ИЛИ?

Может кто-то форкал либу или есть более подходящие для этого?

Comment: Какой красивый язык …

Comment: Каким владею, на таком и пишу, сударь